# How to cast the correct data type when INSERTING into MS Access with a SQL string?

Tags: c#, excel, ms-access, casting, type-conversion

I have an Excel table with hundreds of columns and various data types (ints, strings, dates). I am using C# to programatically insert these rows into an MS Access database table.

When I build the query string, all the Excel cell contents become strings. The query string ends up looking like this:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO tbl_Items VALUES ('toy duck', 'yellow', '122', '2015-01-16')"
```

Casting the type in my SQL string with `INSERT INTO tbl_Items VALUES ('toy duck', 'yellow', CLng('122'), CDate('2015-01-16'))` is out of the question due to the quantity of columns be dealt with, and the need for flexible code.

So how can I achieve a flexible programatic insert of multiple datatypes into my Access DB? I don't mind pre-defining the database table inside Access, but I am not sure if it will correctly auto-change the strings coming in. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Oh wow! Simply pre-defining the table column types will work! MS Access automatically converts the strings into the necessary type.

For example:

```
***tbl_Items***
name: String,
color: String,
weight: Number,
delivery_date: Date
```

Will accept and auto-cast the SQL string:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO tbl_Items VALUES ('toy duck', 'yellow', '122', '2015-01-16')"
```

Comment: Yes, as long as the data *can* be converted to the target data type, this will work. Just be careful with date strings, something like `'01/03/2015'` could end up Januar 3rd or March 1st, depending on regional settings or the current moon phase. :)  But `yyyy-mm-dd` is safe.